# How to handle semicolons when generating a CSV file?

Tags: node.js, csv, npm

I am using the NPM module [json-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-csv) to generate a CSV file from an array of objects. However, some fields might contain a semicolon (`;`), and apparently the CSV gets split at the semicolon, despite the fact that this field is quoted. Can anyone make any suggestions as to how to fix this issue?

The code I use for the options is the following:

```
var options = {
  fields: [
    {
      name : 'paragraphId',
      label : 'ParagraphID'
    },
    {
      name : 'paragraph',
      label : 'Paragraph',
      quoted : true
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to CSV specification, you **can** have delimiters in *values*, as long as you surround these values with double quotes. From [CSV specification](http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm):

> **Fields with embedded commas must be delimited with double-quote characters.**

And:

> **Fields may always be delimited with double quotes.**
>   The delimiters will always be discarded.

Option to trigger this behavior on when exporting data using `json-csv` library is `quoted: true` in the options for a given field - I see that you've already included it, so you're good.

Also - it's worth to note that this library uses comma (`,`) as delimiter by default, not semicolon (`;`). To use different delimiter, alter your options properly:

```
var options = {
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'paragraphId',
      label: 'ParagraphID'
    },
    {
      name: 'paragraph',
      label: 'Paragraph',
      quoted: true
  }],
  fieldSeparator: ';' // the important part!
};
```